# 401 unauthorized error in load runner web service test

Tags: web-services, performance-testing, loadrunner

I want to create script in load runner. I add wsdl and set input variables, when I run my scrip replay failed with 401 error. I need to send user password and authorization algorithm (type) with my web_service_call.
I use web_set_user but it doesn't work. 
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Put this before web_set_user:

web_set_sockets_option("SSL_VERSION", "2&3"); // Not mandatory, if used edit it with your Version
web_set_sockets_option("INITIAL_AUTH", "BASIC"); // Force sending user credentials with the first request without waiting for HTTP 401.